# Presentation and PhysicsBody become separated after collision

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a grid of SCNNodes with static physics bodies and another set SCNNodes with dynamic physics bodies that falls through them. After a collision of the static and dynamic bodies occurs due to gravity the physics bodies keep working but the presentation node of the dynamic bodies fly across the screen multiple times, eventually disappearing. Even limiting the grid to a single node still causes this behavior The only thing I could think of was the parent/child relationships. What would cause this behavior?